# Can the MS Windows Text Service use the IME?

Tags: windows, ime, text-services-framework

I started experimenting with Text Services after reading sources as the [TSF Aware](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tsfaware/) blog
and the [MSDN examples](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/tsf/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1755).

Taking as an example situation when using the Japanese language having built a TS (Text Service) for it, I see the TS on the XP/Vista/Win7 language bar as an alternative to both the MS IME and the Japanese input.

So the user can either use the IME method of input or use my TS among other options. If I build and use the 'CandidateList' MSDN TS example it behaves just like the Japanese method of input with a "dummy" candidate list window popping up which has no implementation.

Can I conclude then that a TS is an alternative to the IME only? Or could a TS add functionality to/make use of the IME? Otherwise I don't pretend to make my own candidate selection althorithm and people used to/prefering the IME would not use my TS then.

Could a TS call the IME thus giving the same end results?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the IME is implemented using TSF.  TSF does not define a canonical way for one text service to communicate with another.